# Excel Dynamic Array Spill Area - can it go along a row or just down a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

The point of this exercise is to try to make this analysis quicker/easier to update.  I had it pretty dialed in using a data tab and a pivot table, copying and pasting values/formulas as needed to update.  I am trying to improve on that by using Excel's new Dynamic Arrays.

My table is setup with four employee detail columns (Location Name, Location Number, Employee Name, Employee Number), and several (many) columns for dates worked.  *My issue is the dates worked*.

I am using UNIQUE and FILTER to get a list of flagged employees - works as I intended/hoped; lookup formulas to find the location name and number data for each employee from the data table - works as I intended/hoped; and I have been copying/pasting the dates from the pivot table column headers into my "counting"/analysis table header.

***What I would like to do is use the UNIQUE formula to get the dates worked - BUT, I want the spill area to go along the row so the dates are column headers.***  Okay, I probably could have made that a shorter ask, but I hope explaining a little of what I'm trying to do helps.  I want the dates to automatically update when I paste new payroll/hours worked data into the data table, the same way the employee data updates.

Comment: Curious why this got down-voted.  I believe it is a legitimate question - my table would be easier/quicker to update if I could make the spill area for dates go along the row as column headers.

Comment: As to why you got down voted, my guess is that all we see is a wall of words.  If you would show the formula you tried and maybe some mocked up data and expected output it would help us better understand the problem.  A wall of words is off putting and hard to understand at times.  Remember that we are volunteers using our own time. And one should show more than explain.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  I come on here a lot for answers but haven't asked many.  I actually edited this question to make it more reader friendly.  I probably should have just gone with the one line question.  And thank you for your answer below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to TRANSPOSE the UNIQUE formula, not the data:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A1:A9))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find anything about having the spill area go along a row instead of down a column.  My workaround for this was to create a column of unique dates next to my data table.  Since the data is in a table, the unique dates will update automatically when the table is updated.  I used the Offset formula to pull the dates into my column headers from the column of Unique dates next to my data table. I will say, while this setup is easier than updating via the pivot table, it is a formula heavy workbook now.

For the data headers I used : "=OFFSET('Data Table Tab'!$U1,Column()-5,0)".  The "rows to offset" portion of the formula is "Column()-5".  My first date header is in column 5, so as it is copied to the right this will increment the number of rows to offset from the first date.

At this point I will just need to copy the formulas over to the right to update my analysis table.

I would be surprised if someone else out there just starting to work with the new Dynamic Array formulas in Excel doesn't wonder about the same thing.  If you stumble across this question and have a better solution, please feel free to share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

Confirming you can just put Transpose([spill formula]) to make a row to column or column to row